# Does Battle Royale and Save The World share any cosmetics or microtransactions?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale, fortnite-save-the-world

Does Fortnite Battle Royale or Fortnite Save The World share any cosmetics or microtransactions? If I buy skins, dances, or pickaxes in Battle Royale, can I use them in Save the World?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, with Season 10, some items are able to be used in both gamemodes.  Specifically:

- Dances
- Emotes
- Toys
- Loading Screens
- Music Kits
- Banner Icons

Other [cosmetics that work in both modes but isn't in-game yet are](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/news/stw-locker-blog-1):

- Pickaxes
- Wraps